# understanding meaning of 'cuttie'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, nouns, vocabulary, transatlantic-differences

Urban Dictionary tends to [describe the word **cuttie**](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cuttie) in quite sexual way. Is it really the main meaning or the noun can be used normally to name a person / thing which is just [cute](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cute).

Comment: I've never seen the word "cuttie", which would be pronounced /kut-ee/, I suppose.  I  have, of course, seen "cutie", a cute person or thing, pronounced /kyoo-tee/.

Comment: I've just searched Urban Dictionary for "cuttie" and only found "cutie". I think there's a bit of fat finger typing here. Is that right or have you found a rare word?

Comment: Someone who is "cute" is a "cutie".  It is not really any more "sexual" than "cute".  "Cuttie" is not really a word.

Comment: Please provide at least one documented example of where you saw this, because as is, it looks like a simple spelling mistake.

Comment: yep I misspelled that s why I couldnt find it in other dictionaries sorry guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**cuttie** [definitions.net](https://www.definitions.net/definition/cuttie)

- cuttie (Noun)

  Short for a cutback.

  cuttie (Noun)

  A t-shirt that has had the sleeves removed.

  cuttie (Noun)

  Someone or something common and short or small.

  cuttie (Noun)

  A hare.

  cuttie (Noun)

  The Black Guillemot.

  cuttie (Adjective)

  Short, shortened or small.

Nothing of a sexual sense found here, U Dictionary sole source.